# Письма от mail.ru не доходят через форму обратной связи

Tags: php

Я искал ответ на этот вопрос прежде чем задать, но найденные мной ответы не решили проблему.

У меня на сайте есть форма обратной связи, вот код:

```html
 <?php
$to = 'mail@mail.ru';

if ( isset( $_POST['sendMail'] ) ) {
 $name = substr( $_POST['name'], 0, 64 );
 $tel = substr( $_POST['tel'], 0, 64 );
 $email  = substr( $_POST['email'], 0, 64 );
 $message = substr( $_POST['message'], 0, 250 );

if($_FILES)
{
 $filepath = array();
 $filename = array();
 $file2 = array();
 $i = 0;
  foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
   if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $filename[$i][0] = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $filename[$i][1] = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
    $i++;
   }
  }
 }

 
 $body = "Имя:\r\n".$name."\r\n\r\n";
 $body .= "Контактный номер:\r\n".$tel."\r\n\r\n";
 $body .= "E-mail:\r\n".$email."\r\n\r\n";
 $body .= "Описание заказа:\r\n".$message; 
 send_mail($to, $body, $email, $filename);
}




// Вспомогательная функция для отправки почтового сообщения с вложением
function send_mail($to, $body, $email, $filename)
{
 $subject = 'Новый заказ с сайта';
 $boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time())); // генерируем разделитель
 $headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n";  
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n";
 $multipart = "--".$boundary."\r\n";
 $multipart .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
 $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n";

 $body = $body."\r\n\r\n";
 
 $multipart .= $body;
 foreach ($filename as $key => $value) {
  $fp = fopen($value[0], "r"); 
  $content = fread($fp, filesize($value[0]));
  fclose($fp);
  $file .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";
  $file .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
  $file .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
  $file .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$value[1]."\"\r\n\r\n";
  $file .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content))."\r\n";
 }
 $multipart .= $file."--".$boundary."--\r\n";
 mail($to, $subject, $multipart, $headers);
}
?>
```

Этот код работает. Приходят письма, если указать почту отправителя Gmail или Yandex. А вот если указать ...@mail.ru, то письма с формы не приходят. Что я уже сделал, но не помогло:
 1. Указал почту с хостинга
 2. Установил у регистратора DNS от бизнес mail.ru
 3. MX-записи настроены верно, SPF-запись настроена верно, Подпись DKIM включена

Где еще искать причину?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не имеете никакого права прописывать в отправителе ни Gmail, ни Yandex, ни mail.ru. Подобные письма обязаны лететь в спам, потому что выдаёте себя за другого пользователя, и если на Gmail и Yandex не полетели — вам просто повезло. Вы должны отправлять все письма только со своего собственного домена.

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать Яндекс.ПДД или бизнес-почту mail.ru, вы должны настроить PHP таким образом, чтобы он отправлял почту через них. И опять же использовать только свой собственный домен и не подставлять никаких чужих доменов в отправителе.

Comment: andreymal, возможно я так написал, что вы меня неправильно поняли. Я напишу на примере. Допустим, я клиент, и хочу через форму написать, указав свою почту gmail. В этом случае администратор сайта получит сообщение. А вот если клиент в форме укажет свою почту mail.ru, то до администратора сообщение через форму никогда не дойдет.

Comment: Потому что вы пихаете почту клиента во `From`, чего делать категорически нельзя

Comment: Значит проблема решается редактированием кода ? Не могли бы подсказать, что нужно изменить ?

Answer (score 1):

Удалил:

```html
$headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
```

Теперь работает.

Answer (score 0):

Метод mail.php признан потенциально опасным хоть ты весь домен обвешай метками непонятным и странным способом через какой-то DKIM!!)) Забей на это!!!
Работай через адекватный метод!
https://github.com/Ipatov/SendMailSmtpClass

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Но пока работает, трогать не буду.